# Access to EVAP Canister Vent Valve

Tags: emissions, acura

My TSX is coding P2422 - EVAP Canister Shut Valve close malfunction.  I'm finding posts online that it is often a blockage (spider nest??) that can be blown out with air.  I'd like to try that first before parts and labor to replace.

How can I access the EVAP Canister Vent Valve?

Can the repair wait until a warm spring Saturday without consequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was just a spider laying eggs in the valve.  Asked the dealer to try blowing it out with the compressed air.  Been working ever since, no problems.  Apparently the spiders like the smell of inside there and this is a somewhat common problem documented in the service knowledge bases for this car and several others.

Answer (score 2):

Instructions [here](http://tl.acurazine.com/forums/showthread.php?t=729920).  The canister is under the driver's side passenger seat and you need to jack the vehicle up (secure with jack stands) and remove the nearest wheel.  Remove tubing, electrical connector and one bolt and it comes out.  Once out, you can replace the whole thing or hopefully just replace the valve.  Sounds like something I could do on a Saturday, but your mileage may vary.  You'll need a jack and some jack stands, socket wrench with extensions, and some common socket sizes since the post does not list the size.  Good luck!